# Desktop Workspaces are separated

Tags: 16.04, workspaces

In 16.04 the desktop switching suddenly stopped working.
- the list shown in Alt-Tab contains only the apps on current workspace
- the hotkeys don't work any more for switching
- if I activate an app on another workspace the workspace is not switched like before, so the app remains off-screen.

What did I screw up?

Comment: See if a reboot fixes the problem. Otherwise, Compiz Config should allow you to check/reset these values. Report back. Cheers, Al

Comment: is the problem fixed now? can we have an update?